# Application Icon badge Count is showing 2 for the first install

Tags: ios, ios5, uilocalnotification, badge

I am using UILocalNotifications in my application, When i am launching the app for the first time badge count on app icon shows 2. Same thing is happening when i installed the app with IPA file.if i opened the application once and enters in to background then no badge count is showing.
I am using the following code to set the badge count to 0 for the first time.

```
 if ( ! [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"FIRSTRUNCOMPLETE"] ) {
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber=0;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"FIRSTRUNCOMPLETE"];
```

What should i do to make the badge count as 0 for the first installation.

Comment: where you wrote the code? I mean is it in Appdelegate?

Comment: in Appdelegate- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{///} method.

Comment: try this-> application.applicationIconBadgeNumber =0;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually happens when you deleted the app (while it was showing some badge number), and re-installed it again. It should not show after the app has completed running for the first time after install. If you still see the badge after setting *applicationIconBadgeNumber*, then the problem could be somewhere else.